I need a formula in Excel to calculate the total of resources cost per project
I need a formula to give me the total cost of the resources who worked on a specific project as I have multiple projects and resources but I need to get the exact total


Which formula have you already tried and where are you stuck?

Have you tried something like this? =SUM(B3:F3*$B$2:$F$2)

If you are trying to get the Total Cost Per Project then could try one of the followings:


• Formula used in cell G3 the below formula needs to fill down!
=SUM(B3:F3*$B$2:$F$2)


• Or using BYROW() if you are using MS365 then:
=BYROW(B3:F12,LAMBDA(α, SUM(α*B2:F2)))


• Or using MMULT()
=MMULT(B2:F2*B3:F12,{1;1;1;1;1})


Also, I am not sure what you are referring to by resources in your OP, seems like you might be looking for per resources what was the cost then:


• Formula used in cell I3
=LET(
     α, TOCOL(IF(B3:F12<>"",B1:F1,NA()),2),
     δ, TOCOL(IF(B3:F12<>"",B2:F2,NA()),2),
     SORT(UNIQUE(HSTACK(α, MMULT(N(α=TOROW(α)),TOCOL(B3:F12,1)*δ)))))


• Or Using MAP()
=LET(
     α, TOCOL(IF(B3:F12<>"",B1:F1,NA()),2),
     δ, TOCOL(IF(B3:F12<>"",B2:F2,NA()),2),
     φ, TOCOL(B3:F12,1),
     ε, UNIQUE(α),
     SORT(HSTACK(ε, MAP(ε, LAMBDA(Σ, SUM((Σ=α)*φ*δ))))))


NOTE: In the above formula one can use IFS() in place of IF() as well, then remove the NA() but i have found IF() is more quicker than IFS().

Another shorter way you could do:
=SORT(TRANSPOSE(VSTACK(B1:F1,
 BYCOL(B3:F12,LAMBDA(α,SUM(α)))*B2:F2)))


Or, Using MMULT()
=LET(
     α, IF(B3:F12="",0, B3:F12), 
     SORT(TRANSPOSE(VSTACK(B1:F1,
     MMULT(SEQUENCE(,ROWS(α))^0,α)*B2:F2))))



Thank you so much that formula will work for me, i'll just need to change the costs for them to be per day then i'll have the cost per project as i needed

@Mohamed for per day, i think dividing by 22 will work. if weekends are taken as off. also dont you think the month is needed, every month will not have same number of working days

Yeah it's kinda confusing not gonna lie but im trying thing about it cause what i attached is a small sample as we have about 250 projects and 40 developers so i have to think of better ways i guess

@Mohamed You will certainly need the months !
